# How to count rows with Dates and display the unique label date and the total count of events for that date

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet that I'd like to count the total number of records for each date, which is displayed in the Col4 position. So the output should be a table with two columns: Date, and Count. 
The following query returns only the global total count, and the other query returns an error message.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("10OAEb2fBfvAqCdp1yyuTBQ4NErtxtOyJ29whFkvVqaw"; "Data!B:P"); "SELECT COUNT(Col4) LABEL COUNT(Col4)''";1)



=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("10OAEb2fBfvAqCdp1yyuTBQ4NErtxtOyJ29whFkvVqaw"; "Data!B:P"); "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Col4) LABEL COUNT(Col4)''";1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming date is in column `Col4`:
`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("10OAEb2fBfvAqCdp1yyuTBQ4NErtxtOyJ29whFkvVqaw"; "Data!B:P");
 "SELECT Col4, COUNT(Col1) group by Col4";1)`

You need to count some other column (Col1).

More `sql` syntax for sheets here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage